# FOSUserBundle or PUGXMultiUserBundle to have two different user profiles (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm doubtful about how to approach this problem:

My Symfony2 app for this issue has two different profiles, name 'em "Seller" and "Buyer". The goal is to keep a bunch of attributes about a "Seller", and, on the other hand, not much about the "Buyer" (email and password would do it).

I realise that it's not easy to have two different entities log in and register using FOSUserBundle. There are quite some other bundles, such as PUGXMultiUserBundle that 'hack' FOSUserBundle, and are not easy to config/implement.

So my quiestion is: Is it more correct to use the hack PUGXMultiUserBundle proposes, dealing with its implementation and config, or is it better to stick to FOSUserBundle, have a User entity, and a one-to-one relation with a "Seller" entity that represents the attributes of a Seller different from a buyer? There would be another problem with that approach, with the registration form, that should be splitted in two, for Seller and Buyer register (which I don't know if it is possible/advisable using FOSUserBundle)

I hope you guys help me get it right. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely use the [`PUGXMultiUserBundle`](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) for that. I don't think it's a hack, it just implements a discrimination table that will be like:

<kbd>1</kbd>User Table

```
----------------------------------------
| id  | username  |  type  |------------
|-----|-----------|--------|------------
|  1  |  mgdepoo  | buyer  |------------
|  2  | Sydney_o9 | seller |------------
----------------------------------------
```

<kbd>2</kbd>Buyer Table

```
----------------------------------------
| id  |  buyer_specific_field_1
|-----|---------------------------------
|  1  |  
----------------------------------------
```

<kbd>3</kbd>Seller Table

```
----------------------------------------
| id  |  seller_specific_field_1
|-----|---------------------------------
|  2  |  
----------------------------------------
```

That's all there is really.

I think that's exactly what you need especially if you wish to have different profiles for your users. You will have 2 registration forms as well (but you can make one with a choice box buyer/seller if you want to).

I personally use this bundle and it works great for me. Now, one of the question you might want to ask yourself is what if a buyer wants to be a seller as well. Does he want to have another email address? That is a choice that you'll have to make.

Comment: Thank you, this approach is indeed quite simple (more than I thought) and it's working pretty well.

Comment: @Mick : is correct using roles to make difference between users without adding new attributes 'type'  ?