# persist parent and child entities using FOSUserBundle and "JOINED" Class Table Inheritance Doctrine 2/Symfony2.7

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I am using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) in order to manage my users into my application. 
But in fact, I have multiple user entities: `ParticularConsumer.php` and `ProfessionnalConsumer.php`. So I create a `ParentUser.php` entity who as an **abstract class** who extends `BaseUser` of *FOSUserBundle*. See the code here:

```
/**
 * ParentUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parent_users")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"particular_consumer" = "ParticularConsumer", "professionnal_consumer" = "ProfessionnalConsumer"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\EntityBundle\Repository\ParentUserRepository")
 *
 */
abstract class ParentUser extends BaseUser
{
/**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="pusr_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    // ...
```

So there are the two other entities who extend the `Parentuser.php`, following the [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) of *Doctrine* behavior and documentation:

First `ParticularConsumer.php`

```
/**
 * ParticularConsumer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="particular_consumer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\EntityBundle\Repository\ParticularConsumerRepository")
 *
 */
class ParticularConsumer extends ParentUser
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

Second `ProfessionnalConsumer.php`

```
/**
 * ProfessionnalConsumer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="professionnal_consumer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\EntityBundle\Repository\ProfessionnalConsumerRepository")
 *
 */
class ProfessionnalConsumer extends ParentUser
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

Now, that I would like to do and to know is how to persist the parent and child entities.

Indeed, as I use the *FOSUserBundle*, all the routes (register,login, etc...) are managed and generated by this bundle. Now I need to persist datas in  Child entities, normally it persists datas in parent entity, that's right ? How can I proceed exactly ?

---

**This how I need to proceed to register a consumer:**

There is a question on a page, whish ask users if there are
professionals or particulars.

A drop down list is here for them to make the choice.

Following the choice, I need to register the user in the right entity.
If the user choose **particular** in the drop down list, I need to
**load/display** a form to persist data in `ParticularConsumer.php` and not only in `ParentUser.php`.

**But as I use the FOSUSerBundle, I don't really know how to proceed exactly. As you can understand, using the *FOS* is a practical way in order to manage users and manage the security, I would like to keep the logic of the bundle. And I want to use the good practices.**

Finally, following all the doc of the *FOSUserBundle* in order to install it, if I want to register a user (`localhost/web/app_dev.php/register`) I have this error:

> Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class MyBundle\EntityBundle\Entity\ParentUser

Answer (score 1):

If your `ParentUser` is an abstract class then it cannot be an `Entity`. In such case you have to make it to a **[MappedSuperClass](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)**. But as you can read in the documentation:

> A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only). This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped superclass at all. Furthermore Many-To-Many associations are only possible if the mapped superclass is only used in exactly one entity at the moment. For further support of inheritance, the single or joined table inheritance features have to be used.

If you want to be able to query your `ParentUser` and you want this class to have its own entity repository then you will have to remove `abstract` and add a value for `ParentUser` to your `@ORM\DiscriminatorMap` definition:

```
@ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
    "parent_user" = "ParentUser"
    "particular_consumer" = "ParticularConsumer",
    "professionnal_consumer" = "ProfessionnalConsumer"
})
```

Comment: I understand now that `ParentUser.php` need and have to to be a base for other user class (`ParticularConsumer.php` and `ProfessionnalConsumer.php`). But as you understand, I need to extend the FOSUserBundle logic (registration, profile, connexion) to the child entity. How can I could proceed for that ?

Comment: Like I said to make this work you should make `ParentUser` either to an Entity or a MappedSuperClass. Why do `ProfessionnalConsumer` and `ParticularConsumer` not extend `BaseUser` directly?

Comment: I don't know if FOSUserBundle could be extends on many entities, I have not tried yet ? Is it possible ?

Comment: @french_dev It is an abstract class. I would be surprised if it is not possible. But I have no first hand experience with it...

Comment: Thank you for your help, of course it is an abstract class, I will tried to code what I need in extending the FOS two times.

Comment: @french_dev Did it work our for you? Or still looking for alternatives?

Comment: I am still looking for a better alternantive, I tried to extends the BaseUser of FOS on many users entities, but as you can see on the doc, FOSUserBundle is made fto extend the BaseUser on only one one entity. I am looking for something more appropriate to my application. If I found something better, don't worry I will post here some more informations. Thank you by the way.

Comment: @french_dev And did you try my other suggestion: making `ParentUser` to an entity and adding it to the discriminator map? I think it will work like that too... Or make `ParticularConsumer` to parent and let `ProfessionnalConsumer` extend `ParticularConsumer`

Comment: check this question on stack [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043055/fosuserbundle-or-pugxmultiuserbundle-to-have-two-different-user-profiles-symfon). This is not exactly what I need to, even if I need a `ParentUser`. But, I f I have not found another solution I will try yours like the link show.