# Symfony & FOSUserBundle: 3 different profiles, depending on role

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony

I've a **User** class

```
# User
- id
- username
- password
- email
```

and three different **roles** with different **profile fields**:

```
# 1. Teacher 
- teachingSince
- aboutMe
- classes

# 2. Pupil
- class
- parents
- dateOfBirth
- grade

3. Parent
- children
- phoneNumber
```

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043055/fosuserbundle-or-pugxmultiuserbundle-to-have-two-different-user-profiles-symfon) the [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) was recommended.

I'd like to use the **FOSUserBundle** to achieve that. Does anyone know how I can define different profiles by role?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be lots of ways to do this.

### Simplest

the user entity class contains all the fields, you have a base form-type for user which contains only common fields for all three 'roles', then extend those for each role adding the necessary fields.

**Base form type**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
      $builder->add('username', TextType::class, []);
      // etc etc
  }

  // ...
}
```

**Teacher**

```
class TeacherType extends UserType {

  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
      parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

      $builder->add('teaching', DateType::class, []);
      // etc etc
  }

  // ...
}
```

### complicated way (I would probably go this way)

use a mapped superclass `User`, extend it for each 'role'.  This will need some attention on the auth side (use [Guard](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-guard-authentication-component)).  But as I hate FOSUserBundle with a passion I'm probably biased to this solution.